# Is there currently a way to compute a dart function with webworkers?

Tags: flutter, dart, web-worker, dart-isolates

I am currently trying to run a A* seek computation on flutter web

```
class AStarSeeker extends Seeker {
  @override
  Future<Path> Function() seek(SeekComputationInput input) {
    return () => compute(doComputation, input);
  }
}

Future<Path> doComputation(SeekComputationInput input) async
{
  return Path.empty;
}
```

But I read that compute() does not currently work on flutter web. Is there a way that I can run my dart function with a webworker? I read that you can run js functions but couldn't find anything about dart functions.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you can use raw `Isolate`s in Dart. Read the official doc about isolates, which are just like threads in other languages.

By the way this link may be helpful: [Dart: in browser webworker written in dart and used in dart2js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462530/dart-in-browser-webworker-written-in-dart-and-used-in-dart2js) and https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.0/dart-html/Worker-class.html

**UPDATE**

Sounds like isolate does not work in web. Then what about the "Worker" approach I mentioned above. Notice that you can always compile your dart code to a `js` file, so even if Worker only supports js you can still execute dart there.

This https://dev.to/kyorohiro/isolate-at-flutter-for-web-28lg sounds like a good tutorial.

The core part:

```
parent.dart

import 'dart:html' as html;

main() async {
  if(html.Worker.supported) {
      var myWorker = new html.Worker("ww.dart.js");
      myWorker.onMessage.listen((event) {
        print("main:receive: ${event.data}");
      });
      myWorker.postMessage("Hello!!");
  } else {
    print('Your browser doesn\'t support web workers.');
  }
}

child.dart

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html' as html;

import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'package:js/js.dart' as pjs;
import 'package:js/js_util.dart' as js_util;

@pjs.JS('self')
external dynamic get globalScopeSelf;


Stream<T> callbackToStream<J, T>(String name, T Function(J jsValue) unwrapValue) {
  var controller = StreamController<T>.broadcast(sync: true);
  js_util.setProperty(js.context['self'], name, js.allowInterop((J event) {
    controller.add(unwrapValue(event));
  }));
  return controller.stream;
}

void jsSendMessage( dynamic object, dynamic m) {
  js.context.callMethod('postMessage',[m]);
}

main() {
    callbackToStream('onmessage', (html.MessageEvent e)  {
      return js_util.getProperty(e, 'data');
    }).listen((message) {
      print('>>> ${message}');
      jsSendMessage(js.context, 'callback: ${message}');
    });
}
```